# Using Apache to silently redirect requests

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm actually using php to send a "301 Moved Permanently" header and redirects users to a easy-read address:

`www.mywebsite.com` to `www.mywebsite.com/home`

is there a way to do that with Apache ?

1. User is requesting a url
2. Server reads the .htaccess file and prepares the right page ( `/mywebsite/home/index.html` instead of `/mywebsite/index.html` )
3. It sends the page and appropriate headers used to warn the browser that the new URL is `www.mywebsite.com/home` (not to use any JavaScript)

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, you need something like this: `RewriteRule ^/$ /home [L,R=301]` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the time and experience growing, I can answer my own question,
>   Hope this will help users that begin with apache :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /home [R=301,L]
```